# Scrolling not working on page reload - Angular ng-repeat bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar

I'm having a weird bug with Angular.

Here's the context: The page loads with everything fitting in the window. The user clicks on something and a bunch more content loads. An ng-repeat pushes the document height below the fold, the vertical scrollbar appears, and the user can scroll down to view the rest of the content. Everything works.

If I scroll to the bottom, and then refresh the page, the scroll position jumps back to the top of the page and everything is reset. If I click to load the additional content again, it shows up, but the scroll is 'locked'. The scrollbar still appears, but scrolling with the scrollwheel is impossible.

All the site functionality works, but I cannot scroll down with the mouse (or using the arrow keys). If I click and drag the scrollbar down, it fixes the issue and scrolling is restored.

To make matters worse, the bug only happens about 10% of the time. The rest of the time, the page happily scrolls just fine.

**Some clues I've found:**

Inside the Angular controller, I added the following:

```
console.log( $(window).scrollTop() );
```

This snippet logs whatever the scrollTop value was *before* the page load. It logs this every time, even the times when scrolling works fine.

Even more confusingly, in the HTML itself, I added the following event listener:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
  console.log("Scroll event logged. Current scroll position: ", $(window).scrollTop());
})
```

This consistently logs, on page load, that a scroll event was detected, and that the scrollTop is now 0.

Even more confusingly, sometimes, when the scrolling does work and the additional content is added, it jumps me straight to the bottom, as if I started scrolling from the bottom.

**What I think is happening**

I think when the page reloads, it retains its now-impossible scrollTop value. Since the scrollTop is below the document height, the browser tries to scroll back up to zero, but this mechanism is buggy and unpredictable.

---

Does anyone know a surefire way to reset the scroll position to the top of the page, on page load? Simply using $(window).scrollTop(0) isn't working. I'm hoping someone understands the lower levels of this mechanism (or knows another way around it).

I've tried a number of dirty hacks (like scrolling the window by 1px when the additional content gets loaded), and nothing seems to be working. I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now and it's driving me a bit insane.

Also, I'd love to put this in a JSFiddle, but since you can't refresh a JSFiddle page without losing all the code (or having it reset to a non-running state), it wouldn't work. Sorry!

Comment: fiddles can be displayed full page

Comment: can you also log the clientHeight and the scrollHeight of the scrollable element at page load? That might be illuminating.

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is I need to refresh the page. When I do so, it 'resets' the script, you need to run it again. Different from how a real page works.

Comment: @PeterAshwell Thanks for the suggestions! I found something interesting.

The 'results' div that holds the dynamic content doesn't exist on pageload (it shows up later with an _ng-if_ that depends on state). So I used clientHeight and scrollHeight on the HTML tag, and got the following values:

**$(document).height():** 716
**<html> clientHeight:** 716
**<html> scrollHeight:** 1196

So yeah, it appears that the scrollheight is greater than the document size. That could be related.

Comment: What happens if you change ng-if to ng-show, does that fix the issue?

Comment: @PeterAshwell also, I switched the _ng-if_ to an _ng-show_, and that container's clientHeight and scrollHeight are both 0 on pageload.

Comment: @PeterAshwell sorry, didn't see that comment! Unfortunately it doesn't fix it.

Comment: The scrollHeight can be greated than the document size, the clientHeight or height() is just what's visible (the height of the browser window). What I was hoping for was some kind of illumination as to the quirky behavior but that doesn't really help. Sorry, good luck. Maybe post more of your code and I can give more hints? Locations of ng-ifs, where the ng-repeat is etc?

Comment: @PeterAshwell mhmm, the thing that perplexes me is _why_ the scrollHeight is greater - there isn't any hidden content, at that point, that extends past the window. But yeah, thanks for your help =) I'll see if I can extract the problem into a simpler document and update my question.

Comment: Oh okay, well, good luck. I'll be watching this question

Comment: This will go nowhere without a demo that replicates issue